# Cache results of properties in python through a decorator

Tags: python, caching, decorator, python-decorators

In my scenario, I have a class with many properties. The properties don't take any parameters, they are heavy in calculation time, and their results should not change during the program lifecycle.

I want to cache the results of those properties, so the heavy calculation is done only once. The approach that I took is with decorators:

```
def cached(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        # get self
        class_self = args[0]
        cache_attr_name = '_' + f.__name__

        if hasattr(class_self, cache_attr_name):
            return getattr(class_self, cache_attr_name)

        else:
            result = f(*args)
            setattr(class_self, cache_attr_name, result)
            return result

    return wrapper
```

and then in the cached class members:

```
class MyClass():
    @property
    @cached
    def heavy_prop(self):
        # In the actual class, the heavy calculation happens here
        return 1
```

Any ideas for a better/other solution for this case?

Comment: Why do you use decorator instead of direct function call?

Comment: I'd generally go for the explicit option that checked whether `_heavy_prop` was `None` (in which case the property would calculate its value and store it in `_heavy_prop`) and returned it otherwise. Are there also times when you'd have to invalidate your cache?

Comment: To build off of @sim was talking a about; What you could do is to define a Class-Variable which should contain the specific value of `heavy_prop` and if the value is not set when calling `MyClass.heavy_prop()` you should set the variable then and there.

Comment: @sim I don't need to invalidate the cache. What you are suggesting is in the constructor of MyClass to define a new member `_heavy_prop=None`, instead of dynamically add it in the decorator as I do?

Comment: @macr0controller: Indeed, that would be my suggestion. In that case it is more obvious to readers of your code what is happening. Of course you pay the "price" that you have to write a check whether your "_protected_" property attributes (e.g. `_heavy_prop`) is `None` in every property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 3.8, use the built in `cached_property`: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property

For older versions, use the library https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property

Or just use this code:

```py
class cached_property(object):
    """
    A property that is only computed once per instance and then replaces itself
    with an ordinary attribute. Deleting the attribute resets the property.

    Based on https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property/blob/master/cached_property.py
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        self.func = func

    def cached_property_wrapper(self, obj, _cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self

        value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
        return value

    __get__ = cached_property_wrapper
```